# how to store and query long text on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, nosql

I have a data set - around 200GB large, that has some long text fields - can be up to 30KB at times, and there are four such fields per row. I am wondering what would be the best way to store this data into a data warehouse on aws, so I can run some analysis on the data. I also need to be able to query the long text itself.

I see redshift has a 65KB limit on text - which is enough, but I'm guessing it's not going to play well with that kind of data. I can use DynamoDB, but it's not the natural choice for a data warehouse...
What's the best way to store this data on aws, so I can query it?

Thanks,
Yaron

Comment: what kind of access do you need? Sequential, by a primary key or multiple other keys? If its just sequential you can probably just do S3

Comment: I'll probably need multiple keys..

Comment: Do you need text indexing (CloudSearch)? Are you able to parse your data before the storage?

Comment: Are you wanting to do a proper text search?  That sounds less like a data warehouse and more like a search problem where CloudSearch or ElasticSearch would be a better fit possibly.